# Cometd - Websocket open / active Connections count in real time

Tags: websocket, jetty, benchmarking, cometd, java-websocket

We are running jetty 9.2.9 on our production with cometd 3.0.1.

We are trying to understand the current load on the system at any given point of time and estimate its maximum scale.

Please suggest the best approach to accomplish the same.

I tried different approaches such as listening the meta channels and keep a count on each message passed and each channel closed. But this does not look like a good approach as this has to touch the meta channels every time and it may also potentially slow down the message passing across channels.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[CometD](https://cometd.org) relies on the Servlet Container implementation of WebSocket, so for monitoring the open/closed WebSocket connections you should probably rely on container features.

For example, if you are using [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) you may look at the JMX MBeans exposed by Jetty about its WebSocket implementation.

If what already exposed is not enough for you, you can probably ask for a feature request (for Jetty, at [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty) URL).